# How does one hide label tags in jQuery Mobile forms in an accessibility-friendly way?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-mobile, accessibility

I want to hide the label tags in my form input tags of my jQuery Mobile application and just rely on placeholder attributes to describe what the specific inputs are for.

However, screen readers rely on label tags to describe what specific form input elements are for. They do not rely on placeholder attributes.

How do I hide the label tags in my forms, while reliably allowing screen readers to read them?

Comment: i'm not positive, but i think you answer may rely in this table http://www.html5accessibility.com/tests/form-labels.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JQM does this with a class. Just add the ui-hidden-accessible to your label tag like so

```
<label for="username" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to apply this class en masse to all label elements?

Comment: Yeah that is quite a bit to type. You could use jquery like $('label').addClass('ui-hidden-accessible');

Comment: Don't forget to mark as answered so that others know this worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can also hide all labels inside of a field container (eg. a DIV) like so

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username"/>
</div>
```

Refer to the [jQuery Mobile documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/forms/docs-forms.html).

Comment: the updated docs http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/forms-label-hidden-accessible/ do it @codaniel's way